# Generating Unique IDs for Rows in React Component - IDs not persisting on renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm working on a React component where I need to generate a unique ID for each row in a table. To achieve this, I'm using the following code:

```
let uniqueID = 1;
return <td style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>{uniqueID++}</td>;
```

However, I'm encountering an issue where the generated unique ID for each row is not persisting across renders. On re-renders, the ID seems to reset or change, and I want the IDs to remain consistent for each row.

Comment: You should use unique id in the array where you are mapping. But you can use `index` as keys *Though it is not recommended*.

Answer (score -1):

In your current implementation, uniqueID is a local variable of your component that gets reinitialized with each render of the component, leading to the observed behavior.

You can add uniqueID property in the data itself.
Pass the data to TableComponent as Prop.

```
const data = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, index) => ({
  uniqueID: index + 1,
  // other properties
}));


const TableComponent = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {data.map(item => (
          <tr key={item.uniqueID}>
            <td style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>{item.uniqueID}</td>
            {/* other tds */}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

<TableComponent data={data} />
```

Comment: Won't this code snippet go `infinite` renders

Comment: Thanks @DecPK for pointing out! I have updated the answer!